# Tkinter checkbox in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to learn python and tkinter since few days.
I would like to create dynamic checkboxes (values from a file) in a frame.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
lst="lst.txt"

class DisplayApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("My Menu")
        self.build_gui()

    def build_gui(self):
        frame_1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, text="Frame 1")
        frame_1.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, sticky='WE',
                            padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        linestring = open(lst, 'r').read()
        for checkBoxName in linestring:
                c = tk.Checkbutton(frame_1, text=checkBoxName,)
                c.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def clicked(self):
        pass

    def main(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = DisplayApp()
        app.main()
```

This is the file lst.txt:

```
laptopname_1
laptopname_2
laptopname_3
laptopname_n
...
```

This the error:

```
[root@hdid_master ~]# ./test_menu_2.py
  File "./test_menu_2.py", line 35
    for checkBoxName in linestring:
                                  ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Many thanks for your help.
Best Regards.

Comment: Your error messages tell you crucial information, reading and understanding it is paramount to help you troubleshoot your code.  In this particular case, the python interpreter is telling you to not mix tabs and spaces together as indents.  Use either all tabs or all spaces in your indents, not a mixture of both.

Comment: Well your error says inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indention. This means you are mixing tab with spaces. Even with correcting tabs and indention I think you need to also fix your checkbutton creations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code error is telling you that you are mixing both `tab`'s and `space`'s that you should not be doing. Python relies on consistent indention to know where a line of code ends and another starts. Please make sure to follow the PEP8 guidelines and use 4 spaces per indention level.

With that said you need to make some changes to your button creation as well. As it is now it will create a different button for each letter of each line.

See below corrected example and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
lst="lst.txt"

class DisplayApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("My Menu")
        frame_1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Frame 1")
        frame_1.grid(row=2, columnspan=3, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        with open(lst, 'r') as lst_file:
            for item in lst_file:
                tk.Checkbutton(frame_1, text=item.rstrip()).pack(side=tk.LEFT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DisplayApp().mainloop()
```

Comment: Many thanks Mike. But now, how can i split the list by column? My file contains maybe 100 iterations

Comment: @Indi59 that is a question for another post. Each question should be specific to one problem for Stack Overflow post. Try it yourself first then ask the question here if you get stuck.